# Пожалуйста, помогите проверить корректность работы программы

Tags: c++, visual-c++, математика, ряды

/* Вычислить бесконечную сумму с заданной точностью eps (eps>0). Считать, что точность
достигнута, если очередное слагаемое по модулю меньше eps, -все последующие
слагаемые можно уже не учитывать.
S = 1 - 2 / 1!+ 3 / 2!- ... + (-1) ^ n * (n + 1) / i!+ ...
*/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 1;
    int fact = 1;
    double s=0;
    double x=0;
    double eps;
    cout << "Введите eps: ";
    cin >> eps;
    do
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fact = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                fact *= k;
                k++;
            } while (k <= i);
        }
        n = i;
        x = ((pow(-1, n)) * (n + 1)) /fact;
        s += x;
        i++;
    } while (abs(x) > eps);
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Ну проверьте, равна ли сумма (-1)^n/n!... Кстати, (-1) ^ n * (n + 1) / i! - может, тогда уж на n!, а не на i!? А вообще, конечно, неправильно. Быстрое переполнение и неверный результат...

Comment: Именно на i, я не вижу ошибок в программе, прошу вас проверить правильность выполнения задачи. Спасибо!

Comment: Поясните тогда, что такое n. У вас формула общего члена ряда зависит от **двух** переменных.

Comment: в данном случае, как я понял, i=n, но в задаче дана именно такая формула нахождения n-го члена

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что, как видите, с точностью eps сумма должна быть по модулю меньше eps. Если у вас так - значит, посчитано правильно. А предел при n стремящемся к бесконечности - просто 0.

А если уж так нужно написать код суммирования ряда - то вот он:

```
double eps, sum = 1.0, term = 1.0;
cin >> eps;
for(int k = 1; abs(term)>eps; ++k)
    sum += (term *=(-(k+1.0)/k/k));
cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: То есть, данная задача с данной формулой будет выдавать правильное значение, верно?